# How Grant Create Foreign Key on another schema?

Tags: oracle

I have two oracle users : User1 and User2.

- User1 has a table **Users_**
- User2 has a table **TestTable**

I'm trying to create a foreign key constraint between the two tables as follows :

```
ALTER TABLE "User2"."TESTTABLE" ADD CONSTRAINT "TESTTABLE_CREATEDBY"
FOREIGN KEY (CREATEDBY) REFERENCES "User1"."USERS_" (ID) ENABLE
```

User2 has the privilege to select on User1 table **Users_** (`Grant select to user2 on Users_`)

When running the alter table statement I'm having an error : of insufficient privileges.

Does anyone know how to solve that please ?

Cheers,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To create a foreign key against a table in another schema we need to have the REFERENCES privilege on that table. This is a separate privilege because it imposes a burden on the table's owner: they can't delete records from their table if you're referencing them. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TTSQL/privileges.htm#TTSQL341)